# G Suit domain email not receiving website emails

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer, google-workspace

I have custom business domain email with gsuite (gmail). Everything works well, but it doesn't receive emails from my business website (website domain name is same to email@ domain name), they don't even arrive to spam.

Website is set to send email with php mail (Wordpress), emails arrive to other emails but not my corporate gmail.

Emails arrive to my corporate gmail only over SMTP, BUT it takes minutes to send email over gmail SMTP (from the website), because of Gmail IPv6 [check the last answer about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068484/phpmailer-using-gmail-smtp-slow-when-sending-emails).

So, SMTP doesn't really work, because nobody will stay 2 minutes on webpage to wait till the contact form is successfully sent.

Why can the corporate gmail reject website emails (same domain on website & emails), and how to fix that?

Comment: SMTP is indeed often inappropriate for sending messages interactively. The solution is to relay through a (fast) local mail server. PHP mail does that anyway, so check your mail server logs for details.

Comment: Thanks I will check the log, let's see If there's something interesting.