# Gmail SMTP Email Sent with no errors but not received by recipient. Sent Email can even be seen in sent folder of the email account

Tags: smtp, gmail, directory

I am sending email using Gmail SMTP, the Emails are Sent with no errors but are not received by recipients. Sent Email can even be seen in sent folder of the email account.

The emails were being delivered earlier but are not now.

Also, how many emails can be sent via gmail smtp per day.

Comment: Has this been resolved or any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this issue? Do you mind sharing how did you work around it?

Answer (score -3):

1. If you are setting incorrect password you will not get any error in
   sending an email but you will not receive the email if password is correct then there might be lots of reason. [see this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/7VutioUikvM)
2. [Gmail Sending Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361233/gmail-sending-limits)

Comment: thanks for reply. no my password is correct. when i see sent folder in gmail.com all the emails sent from code are there, but recipients do not receive them

Comment: then problem might be in recipient email. are you sure that you are entering correct recipient email?

Comment: does recipient's email also gmail?

Comment: yes everything is correct emails were delivered last time. i think they are being treated as spam and but not delivered even in spam folder. can that be the case if so then what to do