# PHPMailer - Could not authenticate

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've been running PHPMailer for a year now on a php server. Everything was fine until 3 days ago when I started getting the following error:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

**Allow less secure apps is ON**

Here is the code:

```
function SendEmail($to,$cc,$bcc,$subject,$body) {
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
try {
$addresses = explode(',', $to);
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $mail->AddAddress($address);
}
if($cc!=''){
   $mail->addCustomHeader("CC: " . $cc);
}
if($bcc!=''){
   $mail->addCustomHeader("BCC: " . $bcc);
}
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 587;   
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "myemailpass"; // SMTP password
$webmaster_email = "myemail@gmail.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$name=$email;
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "Service";
//$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email, "DiFractal Customer Service");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
return $mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
 $myfile = fopen("debug_email.txt", "w");
            fwrite($myfile,$e->errorMessage() . "\n" . $mail->ErrorInfo);
            fclose($myfile);//Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
$myfile = fopen("debug_email_stp.txt", "w");
            fwrite($myfile,$e->getMessage());
            fclose($myfile);//Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
            }
}
```

Note I just updated PHPMailer to the latest version to try to remedy the problem but nothing has changed! The old version 5.2.2 was still having the same problem!

EDIT: I just had one successful email go through to google and sent properly. Which now makes me question if it's lag issue or something of that sort. Does anyone know how phpmailer functions under high loads or if high loads can cause the above error?

Comment: A very common question. Have you checked [**google**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=phpmailer%20gmail%20could%20not%20authenticate)?

Comment: @Michael_B Of course. Standard process for me is to research the 1st page of search results from google before posting on stack.

Comment: Standard process for me, when a question is very common, is to ask. Most aren't as diligent as you :-)

Comment: @Michael_B I try :) Let me know if you think of something. It may even be obvious... sometimes it take someone else to see what I can't

Comment: @Rhopercy Yes sir. As I said this was working for a full year on version 5.2.2 and today it broke. So I updated to latest version but see the same error regardless

Comment: Have you tried to up your debugging and look at all the communication between PHPMailer and the server? You can do this by setting `SMTPDebug` to `4`. I had a script utilizing PHPMailer recently stop working because the certificate on the server had been changed and was not trusted due to not being signed by a CA that was recognized. I saw the exact error message in the mess of communication.

Comment: I believe I may have exceeded the gmail cap on email. The error messages from PHPMailer do not give detailed information to come to that concussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361233/gmail-sending-limits%5d

Comment: Turning up debug output will certainly give you a clearer idea of why it's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you check google's usage limits! PHPMailer will not tell you particulars it will just give you the Could not authenticate error but the reason why can be because of your limits.

@ https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

Upgraded to a new account with google business and switched to that account. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to: 
*myaccount.google.com* -> *"connected apps & sites"*, and turn *"Allow less secure apps"* to *"ON"*.
Alternative:
Try changing SMTP Port to: 465 (gmail also).

Comment: Your first suggestion is already confirmed in the question (see **bold** text).

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues and needed to set the from address

```
$mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'Webmaster');
```